# Move Tabs Down Without Affecting Anything Else

Tags: html, css

I finally fixed a problem with fading, then ran into another. To keep my tabs on the screen and not cut the top halves, I moved them down a bit: this caused the page content to show above the part where the page content fades below the tabs. Any ideas anybody?

I've already tried adding `<br />` tags before the tabs. Here is the code for the test website: [it's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GameShank/z2p4g/1/)! In the jsfiddle, the top halves of the tabs are cut off.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't show the issue unless I am missing something.

Comment: Look at the tabs, the tops are cut off.

Comment: Fixed answer per specs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add padding to the top of the navigation and increase the height.

```
        .top-nav{
            background-color:#181818;
            height:55px;
            padding-top:20px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I honestly can't remember what other CSS I changed but it was tiny things here n there.  This was the gist of it though:

No `html { margin... }` but this was changed:

```
.top-nav {
    padding: 8px;
}
.nav-container {
    background-color:#181818;
    height:35px;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
}
```

Just use the whole CSS because I'm pretty sure that wasn't the only thing I fixed.

**Oh yeah** and, I don't know what `.menu-fade` even does, but it sure doesn't seem useful.  Removing it doesn't change the layout at all.

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zX65h/)

*PS - seeing `<br><br/></br><br />` or any combination thereof makes my foot itch.*

Comment: The only problem with the margin is that it causes the page content to show above the tabs when you scroll. Look above the tabs in your jsfiddle and you'll see the issue.